# Calling C functions from julia on windows 7 (64bit)

Tags: julia

Version 0.6.0-pre.alpha.34 (2017-03-03 04:10 UTC)

Now all the documentation I ever find for this looks like this

```
ccall((:clock, "libc"), Int32, ())
```

The environment I work in doesn't have its libc in his path so I need to specifiy it like this

```
julia> isfile("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\lib\\amd64\\msvcrt.lib") 
true
julia> ccall((:clock, "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\lib\\amd64\\msvcrt.lib"), Int32, ())
ERROR: error compiling anonymous: could not load library "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\amd64\msvcrt.lib"
```

So now I don't know what to do. The error message is useless and afaik msvcrt.lib is the windows libc substitute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`msvcrt.lib` is not a dynamic library but `msvcrt.dll` is and it should be in `C:\\Windows\\system32\\msvcrt.dll` . Since stadard C library loaded by default `ccall` can be used `:clock` without library name.

`ccall(:clock,Int32,())`

Comment: Wow thank you. I wish their documentation would reflect that those arguments are optional.